# Craving sunlight with melatonin?

Tags: sleep-deprivation, melatonin, sun-exposure, sunlight, cravings

I have noticed a very strange, but positive, side effect of taking melatonin supplements or cherries high in melatonin (I have blood tests which confirmed food allergies, and apparently my absorption of melatonin is blocked, in part for this reason).

When I am deficient, I don't like to open the blinds, but I actually consistently actually crave sunlight in the morning when I have sufficient melatonin (and I feel less anxiety (unless taken in too high of an amount, in which case I feel depressed), I better experience and remember dreams, and I am actually able to engage in prayer, which is something that has been hard for me to muster the energy for while deficient, despite having enjoyed the activity previously).

Are these effects, in particular sunlight craving, recognized phenomena? Is anyone familiar with a mechanism by which melatonin would do this?

Does melatonin directly cause the craving of sunlight, or does its deficiency turn off the craving to prompt us to find darkness so as to allow our bodies to regenerate it by whatever other process does the generation?

Comment: Most of the physiologic effects of melatonin are predicted according to a [phase response curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_response_curve#Melatonin_PRC). Walking through the entire curve is exhausting even for a very focused question, so it would be helpful to tell us when in the circadian cycle (e.g. # of hours before habitual bedtime) you're taking it.

Comment: I try to take it about one to two hours before bedtime in the evening, and after I wake up is when I notice that particular benefit. I've noticed the other benefits of melatonin during the daytime, e.g., feeling relaxed by cherries or helping me nap, but I don't do this usually and don't recall if waking from a nap after melatonin caused me to crave sunshine too.

Comment: I don't need to know very specific details, btw. I'm mostly just interested to know whether this phenomenon of my craving sunlight is expected/known and if so, secondarily to know for interest's sake, whether sunlight craving is something that acts by a mechanism other than melatonin but is shut off by melatonin deficiency or whether the craving is directly increased by the presence of melatonin.